# PHP code not sending e-mail

Tags: php, html, email, webforms

I have this part of code in my webpage but it isn't working as it should.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {




$email_to = "sth@somewhere.com";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

        }



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

        }



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

   if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

     }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

     }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

      }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

     }

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

        }



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





 // create email headers

   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

   'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  



    ?>
```

It should send e-mail to the given e-mail.
Also , I want to make it show clear fields after sending e-mail and showing "Message sent".
Please help me!

Nothing happens after adding error report.
Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark" title="First name">
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark" title="Last name">
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark" title="E-mail">
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-use-title-as-watermark" title="Write your message here.."></textarea>
                                </p>

                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control">
                                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>


                            </form>
```

Comment: Start by removing the `@` symbol in `mail()`. You're masking potential [**errors**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Something you're probably not checking for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- still not working

Comment: Your code's execution relies on "email" being set. Add error reporting, by checking the clickable link I gave you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know that my e-mail have to be set.And it is set I just removed from this code here.In website files it is set.

Comment: Not your email, this one `$_POST['email']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is if-statement which makes sure email has been set.

Comment: You're going to need to post your HTML form then. As stated on the subject, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace `}` after `mail()`:

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>
```

Modify it to:

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

}

?>
```

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set, should have shown you something like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /path/to/your/send_form_email.php on line 134

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is now sending e-mails. Can you help me make it show message box and clearing the fields?

Comment: I know JS. I know exactly what I have to add, I just don't know where should I add it.

Comment: You can try inside the inputs themselves. @user3787300 Plus, maybe add JS inside the form tag itself, or trigger it with the submit button.

Comment: +1 You are a trooper for wading through all of that code

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you John. Actually, I put it in my IDE, found the missing brace in a jiffy. However, I did test it fully before posting it as an answer :)

Comment: I just realized that there this code don't show error messages. How can I fix it?